# How To Randomly Pick A Variable Using Rand()

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to make a text based fighter in C++, this is one of the first things that I have done. So far I have this:

```
//Text Based Fighter

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> //srand, rand
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    //Player
    int playerHealth = 100;
    int attack1;
    int attack2;
    int attack3;
    string attack;
    int npc1;
    int npc2;

    cout << "Do you want to attack " << rand()[npc1,npc2];

    //varname = rand() % 10 + 1;

return 0;
}
```

What I am wanting it to do is randomly pick between npc1 and npc2, thank you.

Also any comments on how I am writing my code would be appreciated, I have only started a couple of days ago thank you, if you need any more detail please feel free to ask, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an array of an arbitrary number of variables to choose from:

```
int attack[n];  //For some int-constant n

attack[rand() % n];  //choose a random attack-variable, use it
```

Comment: Note that `rand()` is not very random, see http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 1):

For just 2 choices you can take the remainder from 2 with a ternary expression:

```
int choice = rand() % 2 == 0 ? npc1 : npc2;
```

If you have more than 2 choices, or even if you don't, you can make an array with those and index into it.

```
int npc_choices[2];
int choice = npc_choices[rand() % 2];
```

If the number of choices is not a power of 2 you will likely introduce a very small bias into the selection with the modulo `%` operator. If you're not working on anything with statistical significance or with a huge number of choices I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just two choices in C++11 you can use [std::bernoulli_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution) and here is an overly simplified sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    // give "true"1/2 of the time
    // give "false" 1/2 of the time
    std::bernoulli_distribution d(0.5);

    int npcs[2] = {100, 101};

    int index = d(gen) ? 0 : 1;

    std::cout << "Do you want to attack " << npcs[index] ;
}
```

using an array is more flexible since it expands easily to more than two choices and then you would need to use [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to choose between `[0,N]`.

In the long run using [rand() is not a good idea](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful), although in many simple cases it may work fine. As Pete mentions as long you understand the limitations of `rand()` you can use it and the *C FAQ* has a good section on it, [How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html).

Comment: Gosh, `rand` has been around for forty years and nobody figured out until now that it`s only useful in simple cases. It's a good thing nobody tried to solve any hard problems in all that time.

Comment: @PeteBecker not quite sure what your point is but that presentation is the best summary of the issues I know of and most programmers starting out won't know that. Do you know of a better one, am I missing something?

Comment: Programmers love the fallacy of the excluded middle: if it isn't perfect, it's useless. C++11`s random number facilities can be easier to use, but that doesn't make `rand` useless, tendentiously-titled talks notwithstanding.

Comment: @PeteBecker sure, I don't think I was trying to be so extreme about it but at this point the random header is how we do C++ now. Is there a good reason to not use it if you can, besides for educational purposes to learn what came before and it's limitations?

Comment: Yes, there are good reason to not use it. Like, for example, not having it. Or not understanding how it works, which is often the case here on SO when someone says "don't use `rand`, use this code instead" and the code they write has exactly the same problems that they attribute to `rand`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy to make mistakes when generating pseudo-random numbers. For example, in some cases using `rand() % RANGE` can lead to a subtly-wrong distribution of numbers. (See [this reference](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html) for examples of the problem.)

This may not matter if what you are doing is trivial.

If you want high-quality pseudo-random numbers, there are ways to fix `rand()` (see above reference), but modern C++ also provides `<random>` and `uniform_int_distribution`.

Here’s an example, simulating throwing a 6-sided die, adapted from examples in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html) and the [C++ Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

int roll_die() {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 6);
    return dist(gen);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << roll_die() << std::endl;
}
```

The part that says `dist(1, 6)` could be changed to `dist(0, 1)` to produce output in the range [0, 1] (inclusive) with a uniform distribution.