# Proper boolean random generator (Bernoulli distribution)

Tags: c++, c++11, random, boolean, probability

I'd be curious to know if there is a default random boolean generator in the `random` C++11 library. I've been using a int generator returning `0` or `1` and then converting to bool but I'm trying to optimize my code and thinking that I could save by using from the beginning a bool generator, if it exists.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20527389/1708801) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20646741/1708801) for an example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [`std::bernoulli_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution) in the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header, aptly named after the [Bernoulli distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution).

```
std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 gen(device());
std::bernoulli_distribution coin_flip(0.5);
bool outcome = coin_flip(gen);
```